# jQuery hide parents that have 0 children after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to filter some elements based on its `data` attribute. That part works fine. The problem is that when I'm filtering elements inside multiple parents, so it can happen that a parent finds itself without a child. How can I hide those parents which have 0 children?

Here's the script:

```js
// Filter by size
$(document).on('change', '.filter :radio[name="color"]', function() {
  const size_value = this.value;
  let $products = $('.product').hide();
  let $filtered = $products.filter((i, el) => el.dataset.color !== '' && el.dataset.color.includes(`-${size_value}-`));
  $filtered.show();

  let $collections = $('.collection').hide()
  let $filteredCollection = $collections.filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length > 0
  })
  $filteredCollection.show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="red">
  <label for="red">Red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue">
  <label for="blue">Blue</label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow">
  <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple" id="purple">
  <label for="purple">Purple</label>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="collection">
    Pants
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red--blue-">Red, Blue</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-yellow--purple-">Yellow, Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-blue-">Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="collection">
    Jackets
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red-">Red</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-purple--blue-">Blue, Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red--blue-">Red, Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="collection">
    Hats
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="-blue-">Blue</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-purple-">Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red-">Red</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

After @Barmar 's comment, I updated the script but it won't show anything.
Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarafa/75tj41cu/40/)

Comment: All your collections have multiple children. Do you mean parents with no *visible* children?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sorry

Comment: Then use `$(this).children(":visible").length > 0`

Comment: @Barmar it's not working somehow.. I also tried `children('.product:visible')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The products aren't children of the collections, they're grandchildren. Use `$(this).find(".product:visible")`.

You also need to switch the order of operations. Rather than hiding everything and then showing the ones with children, show everything and then hide the collections with no visible children. This is because the `:visible` selector checks whether it's hidden because the container is hidden, and hiding everything first means nothing will be visible.

```js
// Filter by size
$(document).on('change', '.filter :radio[name="color"]', function() {
  const size_value = this.value;
  let $products = $('.product').hide();
  let $filtered = $products.filter((i, el) => el.dataset.color !== '' && el.dataset.color.includes(`-${size_value}-`));
  $filtered.show();

  let $collections = $('.collection').show()
  let $filteredCollection = $collections.filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".product:visible").length == 0
  })
  $filteredCollection.hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="red">
  <label for="red">Red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue">
  <label for="blue">Blue</label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow">
  <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple" id="purple">
  <label for="purple">Purple</label>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="collection">
    Pants
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red--blue-">Red, Blue</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-yellow--purple-">Yellow, Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-blue-">Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="collection">
    Jackets
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red-">Red</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-purple--blue-">Blue, Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red--blue-">Red, Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="collection">
    Hats
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="-blue-">Blue</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-purple-">Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="-red-">Red</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could also do it as a single selector:

```
$(".collection:not(has(.product:visible))").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Filtering should be ideally part of your JS logic / math, not about an element's children being in a "visible" state - which is computationally more expensive than doing a simple math operation.

Also, since it makes no sense to use `type="radio"` buttons to do filtering (since: *1:* a radio buttons group cannot be unchecked. *2:* you're limiting the user to do actual multiple filtering. *3:* because of 1: the user cannot undo to the initial state.).

**Here's a solution with many-to-many filtering** using `type="checkbox"`:

(the below example uses `","` as dataset delimiter)

```js
const $colors = $(".color");
const $collections = $(".collection");

const filterCollections = () => {
  const colors = $colors.filter(":checked").get().map(el => el.value);
  $collections.each((i, el) => {
    const $pr = $(el).find(".product").show();
    const $ph = $pr.filter((i, el) => !el.dataset.color.split(",").some(c => colors.includes(c)));
    $ph.toggle(!colors.length);
    $(el).toggle(!(colors.length && $pr.length === $ph.length));
  });
};

$colors.on("change", filterCollections);
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="color" value="red">Red</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="color" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="color" value="yellow">Yellow</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="color" value="purple">Purple</label>
</div>
<ul>
  <li class="collection">
    Pants
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="red,blue">Red, Blue</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="yellow,purple">Yellow, Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="blue">Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="collection">
    Jackets
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="red">Red</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="purple,blue">Blue, Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="red,blue">Red, Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="collection">
    Hats
    <ul>
      <li class="product" data-color="blue">Blue</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="purple">Purple</li>
      <li class="product" data-color="red">Red</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great approach! I went with radio for other factors, but alternatively, this is better from an UX perspective

Comment: Thank you!  The same code can be used with `radio` buttons *if really needed* - will work the same - but you're left open with a code you can remake and reuse as a component in different parts of your application. @BenjaminCarafa